# How can I remove items from a JSON array based on a list of array keys?

Tags: arrays, json, node.js

I'm trying to build an API in node.js that syncs two different systems, and I'm having trouble breaking down an array of objects I receive from my source system.
Basically, I receive an array that looks a bit like this:

```
    sourcedata = {
        "items": [
          { "id": "item1",
            "some fields": {...array of some fields },
            "more fields": {another block of fields}
          },
         { "id": "item2",
         "some fields": {...array of some fields },
         "more fields": {another block of fields}
               }]
    }
```

What I also have are three arrays of IDs - new ones (means I have to send them to the target system), old ones (to delete from the target), and ones that appear on both - those I need to check a special tag to see if they are different or not.

e.g.

```
newitems = [id1,id2,id3]
existingItems [id4,id5,id6]
deletedItems = [id7,id8]
```

What I'm trying to do is create new arrays that will only contain the data of the NEW and EXISTING items, so I can process and send them over to the target system without scanning the sourcedata array for each key and deciding what to do . I know how to do that when I compare simple arrays, but here I need the entire objects and all its fields copied over, and I can't 
find the proper way to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function. It filters out elements of array based on your condition. You may use it with the [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function to determine if a thing is in an array. For example:

```
sourceArray = [
  {
    id: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: 'c'
  },
  {
    id: 'd'
  }
]

var toDelete = ['c', 'b']

sourceArray = sourceArray.filter(x => !toDelete.includes(x.id))
// some items in sourceArray have now been removed.
```

Note that `filter` and `includes` may require a recent version of nodejs.

Comment: I managed to do that before, but still not sure how to apply it to my more complex array, and also I'm looking for the most efficient ways to separate the new and existing items from the main array. To delete items from the target system all I need is the ID, but to send over updates I need the entire data set.

Comment: @user3541347 This method should work well for all array. What kind of special requirement do you have that make you think it won't work for "complex" array?

Comment: My mistake - I forgot to reference the array - basically my original variable has the array inside a container, so I had to simply reference the right one.
Works like a charm!